# Render any response from ajax call (HTML and/or JS)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I wonder what's the most effective way to render ANYTHING that might come from an ajax call. The response can be html and/or javascript

I was doing it with document.write() since the ajax call was sync. Now I have to use async calls so I can't just write to the page using document.write, I have to add the content to a specific html object when the call finished.

I tried this

```
   $jQuery.ajax({
   url: "myURL.ashx",
   data: params,
   success: function(data){
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = data;
        document.getElementById('target').appendChild(newdiv);
   }
```

but it doesn't work for any javascript returned, it get easily broken (this means; it doesn't render the content or it does weird things as showing the content in a new tab). I just work for simple scenarios.

I wonder if there is any better approach that works better than this.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

This code, for example, doesn't work as expected. It renders the content on a blank page instead of adding the content to the current page. I'm testing with FF 3.6. For simplicity, I'm harcoding the javscript on `str` var, but that script is returned from the server. The content returned by the server are ADS, the content is dynamic and totally random.

```
        var str = "<sc" + "ript language=\"JavaScript\" type=\"text/javascript\">";
        str += "document.write('<scr'+ 'ipt language=\"JavaScript\" src=\"anything.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"><\/scr' + 'ipt>');";
        str += "<\/script>";
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = str;
        document.getElementById('target').appendChild(newdiv);
```

Comment: "it doesn't work for any javascript returned..." I you are inserting 'data' in your markup, it must be some valid html code, not javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the jQuery equivalent of what you have there would be:

```
success: function(data){
    $('<div />')
        .append(data)
        .appendTo('#target');
}
```

You will have to explain what you mean by

> doesn't work for any javascript
>   returned

for a better answer.

If there are any `<script>` tags within `data` jQuery will evaluate them in the global scope if you use the `jQuery.append` function as I demonstrated above.

### Update

Just remove the `document.write` statement. Only use `document.write` when the page is still loading.

```
<script src="anything.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I edited my post with an example of a non-working script. The jquery approach provided the same result. Thanks!

Comment: @Timmy - you need to remove the `document.write` statement. Just allow the script to load the normal way. Or you could use `jQuery.getScript`

Comment: I finally realized about the problem after I wrote this question. I can't remove the document.write but I'm implementing a workaround. I'm marking your answer as the correct one for following up though. Thanks!

Comment: @TimmyO'Tool - how did you overcome the problem finally

Answer (score 0):

there are  better ways to include js files than making an ajax call that loads javascript. I would look at [.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)