# Rails - why isn't ajax sending params to GET request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to send data through a get request using ajax but the param doesn't seem to be getting sent.  I have a page that shows a random item from the db.  You get to this page from a link in the navbar.  Once on this page there is a link that allows you to skip the current item to find another random item making sure the next item isn't the one the user was just viewing.

**routes.rb**

`get 'pending', to: 'items#pending'`

**view**

```
<%= link_to 'Skip', '', class: "btn btn-default btn-xs",
                     id: "skip-btn",
                     :'data-item-id' => @pending_item.id %>
```

**controller**

```
def pending
    @previous_pending_item_id = params[:id] || 0
    @pending_items = Item.pending.where("items.id != ?", @previous_pending_item_id)
    @pending_item = @pending_items.offset(rand @pending_items.count).first
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
```

I have respond to both html and js because I am using the action for the navbar link as well as the link on the page.  The link on the page is the skip button which should bring up another random item.

**sitewide.js.erb**

```
  $('#skip-btn').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
      data: {id: $(this).data("item-id")},
      url: "/pending"
    });
  });
```

When I look in the server log is says `Started GET "/pending"...` but doesn't make any mention of a param being sent.  What am I missing?

The reason I'm using ajax for this is because I don't want the param showing in the url.

For clarification I need the url when visiting this page to always be /pending with no params or additional :id identified in the url.  This page should always show a random record form the db.  The only reason I need to send a param is to make sure no record is every repeated consecutively even though they are random.

Comment: Do you see the id in the network request?

Comment: @epascarello where do I look for this? I am using chrome browser

Comment: Add a console.log($(this).data("item-id")) to make sure there is something to send

Comment: Add a "p params" at the beginning of your pending action to see in the terminal what's being passed

Comment: Look in the network panel in the developer console in Chrome

Comment: @GrahamSlick yes adding that line to the console shows the correct id

Comment: So you want to get a random `@pending_item` as your response?

Comment: I want the response to be a call to the pending action of the controller and also passing params[:id] to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to prevent default link action:

```
  $('#skip-btn').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
  });
```

Comment: This helped.  Now the terminal shows the param, but now the page doesn't take me anywhere.  The button looks like it's clicked but nothing happens.

Comment: So the reason I'm using ajax is to send information to a controller without it being displayed in the url.  Is there a better way to do this that you know of?  If not, how would I force the page to be refreshed?

Comment: You can re-render the page in response then

Comment: How would I do this.  I tried `format.js {render :action => "pending"}` but doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

While you *can* do it the way you're attempting, I think it's worth pointing out that sending data in a GET request is a bit of an antipattern.  So why not doing it the "correct" way!

Change your **routes.rb** to:

```
get 'pending/:id', to: 'items#pending'
```

and change **sitewide.js.erb** to:

```
$('#skip-btn').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/pending/" + $(this).data("item-id")
    });
  });
```

Comment: I was getting a 404 not found error with your answer so I also tried `url: "/pending?=" + $(this).data("item-id") but now when I click the button nothing happens.  Looking in the terminal it does look like a get request is being sent to /pending?=33

Comment: does not need a ?= for the id field, but it does need the `/` between pending and the id number.  Did you add that?

Comment: yes, but my route is setup not to accept an :id.  When visiting /pending the user record should be random and I don't want users to be able to get back to a specific record.  I want the url on this page to always appear as /pending but I needed a way to send a param so that the same record is never repeated consecutively

Comment: I'll edit my answer then, this is a fair bit different than what you question suggested.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion.  I can try to edit my question to clarify.

Comment: Just to be clear I don't want the url to display any params either.

Comment: Sorry, totally my mistake in understanding; I think I just parsed what your confusion was.  Even though typically the format `get 'route/:id'` correlates to getting the item *with* that id, the logic behind that is controlled by the controller.  You've already modified the controller, so you can gather the param in the traditional way still.

Comment: Why does the link not bring me anywhere.  Do I need to add a new file called pending.js.erb or something?

Comment: Ajax calls don't render anything.  They're typically used to get data, not views, though you *can* use them to get html.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957041/render-any-response-from-ajax-call-html-and-or-js

Answer (score 1):

I'd like you to check for the format its sending the the query to your controller. And the type of format you want to receive at the front end.

```
$('#skip-btn').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json', //This will ensure we are receiving a specific formatted response
    data: {id: $(this).data("item-id")},
    url: "/pending"
  });
});
```

In your controller maybe you want to pass it back as a json object.

```
def pending
  #@previous_pending_item_id = params[:id] || 0
  #No need to make it an instance variable
  previous_pending_item_id = params[:id] || 0

  #Same goes for pending_items. No need to make it a instance variable, unless you're using it somewhere else.
  pending_items = Item.pending.where("items.id != ?", previous_pending_item_id)
  @pending_item = pending_items.offset(rand pending_items.count).first
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @pending_item.as_json }
  end
end
```

So that you can take value from response and append it to your page.

Similarly if you are expecting a `js` or `html` response back, you should mention that in your ajax call. Let me know if it does help you resolve your issue.

> Update:

Let's say in your page, it shows the data of `@pending_item` object in a div,

`<div id="pending_item">...</div>`

When you're making a ajax request to your controller you want div#pending_item to show the a new random pending_item.

```
$('#skip-btn').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'html', //we'll receive a html partial from server
    data: {id: $(this).data("item-id")},
    url: "/pending",
    success: function(res){
      //We'll set the html of our div to the response html we got
      $("#pending_item").html(res);
    }
  });
});
```

In your controller you do something like:

```
format.html { render partial: 'pending_item', layout: false }
```

And in your partial file "_pendint_item.html.erb" you'll access your instance variable @pending_item and display data

This will send the response to server as html, and there you'll only set your div's html to this.

> Update 2

Your partial might look like this, or just however you want to display your pending item. The thing to know is it will be accessing the same instance variable `@pending_item` you have defined in your controller's method, unless you pass `locals` to it.

```
<div class="pending_item">
  <h3><%= @pending_item.name %></h3>
  <p><%= @pending_item.description %></p>
</div>
```

I suggest you do a `console.log(res)` in the success callback of your ajax call to see what you're getting back from server.

Comment: I am confused as to why json is being used here.  I just need to send the id param to the pending action of the controller and render `pending.html.erb`

Comment: Okay. So when you're sending data to your controller via ajax, it doesn't reload your page, or load anything to the page automatically. That's the whole point of using ajax, to do everything asynchronously. So if you want render a page, via a ajax call, you'll have to do it yourself. In our case when we're getting a json response of `@pending_item` object, we'll take it make an html element out of its data and append it to our DOM.

Comment: You say for the partial I will access the instance variable and display data.  What do you mean by this, what should the partial look like?  If I wanted the effect of re-rendering the entire page, does this mean I have to set the partial (`_pending_item.html.erb`)to exactly the same as `pending.html.erb`?